# difficulty with for loops, reading from and writing to files

Tags: c++, for-loop, file-io

I am currently working on a project for my 210 class that involves a file from which I need to extract a full name, flight type, passenger type, membership level, number of bags, and the size/weight of those bags.
It gets very complex with military rewards and mileage clubs, free bags and oversize bags, passenger type, etc... et...

The file looks exactly like this:

```
Mark Spitz E RP NO 2 21.5 24.2 18 6 30 26 20.5 7.5 
Michael Jordan B RP M4 3 53.7 14.1 9.2 15.0 24.2 5.2 9.3 16.2 109.2 12.1 9.6 23.0
Dorothy Hamill E RP NO 2 55.8 27.1 17.2 18.6 15.0 35.2 21.3 9.2
```

This indicates that Mark Spitz is a regular passenger traveling economy class and is not a member of the mileage club. He is checking two bags: the first weighs 21.5 lbs., and is 24.2 in. long, 18 in. wide and 6 in. high; the second weighs 30 lbs., and is 26 in. long, 20.5 in. wide and 7.5 in. high.

I have used for loops to read from infiles before, but never such as this.
I have come to a complete stop and need some serious help with this issue, as I can't seem to find much on it.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated!
Here is my code as current:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int newline, firstname, lastname, flighttype, status, membership, numberofbags=0, regularpass, militarypass, militaryorder, member1, member2, member3, member4, nomember;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("data3.txt");

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("charges.txt");

        infile >> newline;
        for(int a=0; a<newline; a++)
        {
            infile >> firstname  >> lastname;
            outfile <<  firstname  <<" " << setw(10) << left << lastname;
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"reading and writing too and from files"* This makes no sense, please fix.

Comment: @m0skit0: why does it make no sense?  The code opens a file and reads from it; it opens another file and writes to it, doesn't it?  The rest is just 'Use of English', which is probably not the OP's native language.

Comment: You've read the name; you need to read the three char fields.  Then you need to read the number of bags; for each bag, you need to read weight, length, width, height.  What happens when someone has no checked baggage?

Comment: Some of the variables (like names) should probably be `std::string` and not `int`. If you try to read into the wrong type of variable, the stream enters an error state and will refuse to read anything more until the error is cleared.

Comment: Another problem is that what you read next depends on what you read before. So when you read the number of bags, you then have to read that number of bag weights and sizes. This is probably more complicated than you've had to deal with before, but it's not **that** complicated. It just means another loop. I'm sure you've been given all the skills to do this but you just have to put them together in a new way. Really that's what programming is all about.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before the wrong type is being used. You are reading strings into integer variables and that is not going to work.

```
for(int a=0; a<newline; a++)
```

The way you are looping thru the file does not make sense. See the reference below.

[ifstream reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/)

Also...You are not reading in all of the fields before trying to move to the next record. Your data shows some records with more fields than others. That would cause your technique to not work. If the exercise is to read records of the same length than this is the correct code but if it is to read records with variable lengths than this code would not work. You will need to use **getline** to do variable length records.

After seeing *John's* comment above I can see why the record lengths are variable. You need to provide logic that will decide how many fields should be read. I think I can recall now this type of exercise in my 200 level cs classes.